# How to protect media files from being streamed on other websites

Tags: php, .htaccess, stream, media

I know that it's almost impossible to prevent files from being downloaded.
But I know that there's something that can stop them from being streamed on other websites.
direct download, as far as I know is hard to prevent. I know that from my experience downloading youtube videos, however at the same time, using the same link I downloaded youtube video from will not work on an external website player.
So I made my research about it. And I couldn't find what I expected to find.
Can you guys please give me an advise on how to protect my website media files from being streamed online on other websites?

Comment: option 1. check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], option 2 serve all content through a script and use sessions. option 2 is better

Comment: If you are looking for a non-coding way, that would be `HOTLINK PROTECTION` option. Which is available within your Hosting cPanel. Or you could use Cloudflare with Hotlink enabled.

Comment: will the cloudflare protect any files inside a specific directory ?

Comment: the options he is talking about have nothing to do with any specific host, but are available in appache, and still use the HTTP_REFERER approach

Comment: Just a caution that `HTTP_REFERER` based protestion is a weak one and client can send you custom `HTTP_REFERER` header.